# Getting to Kazan (RU) Airport early in the morning

Tags: airports, russia, aeroflot, kazan

I have a flight from Kazan to Moscow that departs at 09:00. How much earlier do I have to arrive at the airport for an inner-Russian flight (I hold a tourist visa) and what is the best strategy to get to the airport from Kazan city center?

Comment: I suppose you mean what are your options to get to the airport by public transportation.

Comment: Yes! I saw that the first aeroexpress train departs at 8:00 wich ich rather late in the morning

Answer (score 3):

If the airport has a website it could be your best friend.

In this particular case [Kazan International](http://www.kazan.aero) provides this information (in Russian and English).

Under section "For Passengers and Guests" there is a section of [How to Get there](http://www.kazan.aero/for-passengers-and-guests/how-to-get/by-bus/) with section specifically [by Bus](http://www.kazan.aero/for-passengers-and-guests/how-to-get/by-bus/).  It lists that there is a bus №97 which starts running at 5 am, though reading some of the [reviews on the bus site (in Russian)](http://bus.kzn.ru/) it could be running every 30 minutes, it's inconsistent, and the first one may not even arrive.

So if you want reliability I would suggest [grabbing a cab](http://www.taxikazancity.ru/) though it is much more expensive 850 vs. 39 Rubles.